# Sitecore 7 replace a page with children

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Hi I have Sitecore 7 and I would like to completely change the content and layout of the main Home page. The home page has 1000's of pages underneath it. What is the best way to achieve this? Is it possible to create a new page and replace the old one with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT create new page and replace the old one with it. There may be many references to the existing home page, not all of them may be easily replaceable.

Instead, create a NEW item and build the whole presentation on the new item. Thanks to that you can prepare and test everything without running your website with incomplete main home item.

When it's ready, you can copy all the content fields and raw value of Layout fields from that item to your home item, publish and that's it.